# Jailshell on cpanel - Allow access to additional folders

Tags: ssh, cpanel, jail-shell

I've not been able to find a solution to this problem.
I'd like clients I give ***jail-shell*** access to (rather than normal shell access) the ability to run commands I allow access too, such as Git.

Git requires you include the folder `/usr/local/libexec/git-core` but I can't work out a way of including the folder for jail-shell access ?

Perhaps it's not even possible, but I'm keen to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mount additional directories in `/var/cpanel/jailshell-additional-mounts`

If the file doesn't exist create it and put the directories which you want to allow into it, one directory name per line:

```
/usr/local/libexec/git-core     
/usr/local/lib
...
```